# SQLAlchemy & pandas: How to query columns with a different label?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

When using pandas `read_sql` to query my database using SQLAlchemy, I get the following warning:

> SAWarning: Column 'id' on table  being replaced by Column('id', Integer(), table=, primary_key=True, nullable=False), which has the same key.  Consider use_labels for select() statements.
>         (key, getattr(existing, 'table', None), value))

Right, so each of my `League`, `Season`, `Round`, `Match`, and `Team` tables have a column named `id`. Of course.

I ignored this at first, but this came to bite me in the buttocks when I wanted to delete one of the columns with the `id` label/name, using `pd.drop()`. Even `pd.rename` referencing the column by its index (!) renamed all columns with the same name:

```
pandoc.rename(
    columns={pandoc.columns[1]: 'match_id'}, 
    inplace=True)
# This replaced all columns with the label `id` to `match_id`
```

SQLAlchemy advises that I use consider use_labels for select() statements, and while I managed to do with with regular queries, I can't really figure out where to stick `.label('new_column_name')` in the following query:

```
pandoc = pd.read_sql(
Match.query.options(
        joinedload(Match.home_team),
        joinedload(Match.away_team)).statement, 
    db.session.bind,
    parse_dates=['date_time'])
```

One option is to change all `id` columns in my tables to `tablename_id`, but that seems like an ugly workaround for a problem that should have a fairly simple solution.

Sample output from `print(pandoc.head())`:

```
   total_goals  id               round_id  \
0          1.0  somestring here  s12786-0   
1          0.0  somestring here  s12786-0   
2          5.0  somestring here  s12786-0   
3          3.0  somestring here  s12786-0   
4          0.0  somestring here  s12786-0   

   home_team_id  away_team_id   id   id  
0           667           664  667  664  
1           669           691  669  691  
2           672           677  672  677  
3           707           686  707  686  
4           699           703  699  703
```

Notice the 3 `id` columns, one is the match ID, the other two are the home team ID and the away team ID.

Comment: Can you simply rename the columns using: df.columns = ['one', 'two', 'etc']

Comment: @Alan: Do you mean set a name on all columns (instead of replace a columns' name)? Because as I wrote in my OP, not only does rename by name rename all columns (as expected), even rename by index (say pandoc[1]/[5]/[6] (those three currently labeled `id`)) renames all of them!

Comment: What was your original read_sql query that triggered the warning?

Comment: @Alan: it's in my OP.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with SQLAlchemy, but I'm thinking you just need to specify tables in your query to keep conflicts from popping up like that. e.g. with a normal sql query you would write "SELECT home_team FROM Team WHERE ..." the key feature being that you've specified a table.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following method of your query:

```
query.with_labels()
```

This will put unique names on every column, and there will be no ambiguity.